CSS transition not working for backdrop-blur
My React/Tailwind app has a mobile menu popup for screens less than 768px wide which uses the Tailwind properties backdrop-blur to blur out everything behind the menu items. I have a transition-all with duration-[400ms] which works to fade in the menu when the button is pressed but there is no transition effect when it is closed.
Below is the code
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useMediaQuery from "../hooks/useMediaQuery";

const Navbar = ({ selectedPage, setSelectedPage }) => {
    const [isMenuToggled, setIsMenuToggled] = useState(false);
    const isAboveSmallScreens = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 768px)");

    const handleToggleMenu = () => {
        setIsMenuToggled(!isMenuToggled);
    };

    return (
        <nav className={`${navbarBackground} text-white bg-darkgrey z-40 w-full fixed top-0 py-3`}>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between mx-auto md:w-[1000px] px-5'>
                <img src={logo} alt="harley-zhang-logo" className="h-6 z-50" />

                {isAboveSmallScreens ? "/* content for desktop menu */" : (
                    <button
                        className="flex justify-between gap-16 z-50"
                        onClick={handleToggleMenu}
                    >
                        {isMenuToggled ? "Close" : "Menu"}
                    </button>
                )}
                <div className={`fixed right-0 bottom-0 h-full w-full transition-all duration-[400ms] transform ${isMenuToggled ? 'opacity-100 bg-darkgrey bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur-xl' : 'opacity-0'}`}>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Navbar;

How can I ensure there is a transition both in and out?

I reproduced your code in a JSFiddle and it seems to be working fine, at least in Chrome.

Try increasing the transition time say to 4000ms and you will see there is transition in both cases as found by @Wongjn - maybe though it things aren't transitioning in the order you expected??

I'm currently using Chrome which is where it doesn't work for me, but I tried safari on both mobile and mac and it seems to work. Is there a reason for this?

As it seems to be working on Chrome at least for some of us, have you checked that you aren't picking up an older version of a css file for example in your Chrome - have you cleared cache for example to ensure you get the latest version?
